# REST URL Design for One to Many and Many to Many Relationships

Tags: rest

Your backend has two Models:

```
One Company to Many Employees.
```

You want to accomplish the following:

```
Get all Companies
Get a Company by ID
Get all Employees for a Company
Get all Employees 
Get a Employee by ID
```

What is the best practice for handling the REST URLs when your models have 1:M relationships? This is what I have thought of so far:

```
/companies/
/companies/<company_id>/
/companies/<company_id>/employees/
/employees/
/employees/id/<employee_id>/
```

Now let's pretend One Company has Many Models. What is the best name to use for "Adding an employee to a Company" ? I can think of several alternatives:

Using `GET`:

```
/companies/<company_id>/add-employee/<employee_id>/
/employees/<employee_id/add-company/<company_id>/
```

Using `POST`:

```
/companies/add-employee/
/employees/add-company/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URIs look fine to me, except maybe the last one, that does not need an additional "id" in the path. Also, I prefer singular forms of words, but that is just me perhaps:

```
/company/
/company/<company_id>/
/company/<company_id>/employee/
/employee/
/employee/<employee_id>/
```

The URIs do not matter that much actually, and can be changed at any point later in time when done properly. That is, all the URIs are linked to, instead of hardcoded into the client.

As far as adding an employee, I would perhaps use the same URIs defined above, and the `PUT` method:

```
PUT /employee/123
```

With some representation of an employee. I would prefer the `PUT` because it is [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence). This means, if the operation seems to fail (timeout, network error occurs, whatever) the operation can be repeated without checking whether the previous one "really" failed on the server or not. The `PUT` requires some additional work on the server side, and some additional work to properly link to (such as forms), but offers a more robust design.

As an alternative you can use

```
POST /employee
```

With the employee representation as body. This does not offer any guarantees, but it is easier to implement.

Do not use `GET` to add an employee (or anything for that matter). This would go against the [HTTP Specification for the GET method](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1), which states that it should be a pure information retrieval method.